# How to save dynamic application data (added widgets within the application itself) in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

**In the application, I add new LineEdit and Pushbutton to the created Gridlayout, and it is necessary that when closed, the data is saved and loaded for the next session. Tell me how to implement this
**
**Here is an example interface**

[image]

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, \
    QMessageBox

from Designer.designerTest import Ui_MainWindow  # Импорт класса Ui_MainWindow из другого модуля


#################################################################################################

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  # Создание экземпляра класса Ui_MainWindow
        self.ui.setupUi(self)  # Инициализация UI элементов

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.ui.widget_2.setLayout(self.layout)  # Установка QVBoxLayout как layout для виджета widget_2

        self.ui.btnSaveTopic.clicked.connect(
        self.create_new_label)  # Подключение функции create_new_label при нажатии на кнопку btnSaveTopic

###########################

    def create_new_label(self):  # Создание новой метки и вызов функции new_grid
        if self.ui.lineTopic.text() != "":
            text = self.ui.lineTopic.text()
            label = QLabel(text)
            label.setStyleSheet('color: white; font: 14pt;')
            self.layout.addWidget(label)

            self.new_grid()  # Создание нового grid

            self.ui.lineTopic.clear()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(None, "Ошибка", "Введите тему")  # Показ предупреждающего сообщения

###########################

    def new_grid(self):  # Создание нового grid layout с элементами
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(grid)

        line_edit = self.create_new_line_edit()
        grid.addWidget(line_edit, 0, 0)

        plus_right = QPushButton()
        plus_right.setFixedSize(20, 20)
        plus_right.setIcon(QIcon("icons/iconPlus.svg"))
        plus_right.setIconSize(QSize(14, 14))

        plus_down = QPushButton()
        plus_down.setFixedSize(20, 20)
        plus_down.setIcon(QIcon("icons/iconPlus.svg"))
        plus_down.setIconSize(QSize(14, 14))

        grid.addWidget(plus_right, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(plus_down, 1, 0)

        plus_right.clicked.connect(lambda: self.create_new_btn_right(grid))
        plus_down.clicked.connect(lambda: self.create_new_btn_down(grid))

        self.column_stretch(grid)  # Установка растягиваемости колонок и строк

###########################

    def create_new_btn_down(self, grid):  # Создание новой строки при нажатии на кнопку вниз
        clicked_widget = self.sender()

        # Получение позиции нажатого виджета в сетке
        for i in range(grid.count()):
            item = grid.itemAt(i)
            if item.widget() == clicked_widget:
                row, column = grid.getItemPosition(i)[:2]
                break
        else:
            return

        line_edit = self.create_new_line_edit()
        plus_right = self.create_new_button(lambda: self.create_new_btn_right(grid))
        plus_down = self.create_new_button(lambda: self.create_new_btn_down(grid))

        grid.addWidget(line_edit, row, column)
        grid.addWidget(plus_down, row + 1, column)
        grid.addWidget(plus_right, row, column + 1)

###########################

    def create_new_btn_right(self, grid):  # Создание новой колонки при нажатии на кнопку вправо
        clicked_widget = self.sender()

        # Получение позиции нажатого виджета в сетке
        for i in range(grid.count()):
            item = grid.itemAt(i)
            if item.widget() == clicked_widget:
                row, column = grid.getItemPosition(i)[:2]
                break
        else:
            return

        line_edit = self.create_new_line_edit()
        plus_right = self.create_new_button(lambda: self.create_new_btn_right(grid))

        grid.addWidget(line_edit, row, column)
        grid.addWidget(plus_right, row, column + 1)

        self.column_stretch(grid)

###########################

    @staticmethod
    def column_stretch(grid):  # Установка растягиваемой колонок и строк сетки
        grid.setColumnStretch(grid.columnCount(), 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(grid.rowCount(), 1)

    @staticmethod
   def create_new_line_edit():  # Создание нового QLineEdit
        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        line_edit.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        line_edit.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black; font: 10pt;")
        line_edit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        return line_edit

    @staticmethod
    def create_new_button(callback):  # Создание новой кнопки
        button = QPushButton()
        button.setFixedSize(20, 20)
        button.setIcon(QIcon("icons/iconPlus.svg"))
        button.setIconSize(QSize(14, 14))
        button.clicked.connect(callback)
        return button

#################################################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried different saving methods using JSON, PICKLE, SQLITE3 but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I normally do: I save each widget data and state in some way that I can retrieve it later, when opening the application a next time.

For this example below (which is not yours, I just created a new one which is smaller, just to show how I do it), I save every widget state (such as text, and user role data), into a python dict object, and use json to save it into a file.

Later on, when the application is loaded another time, that file data is retrieved, and converted back from a Json String into a python dict object. Each of the dict's keys correspond to a widget state defined inside the code, and is used to reset the widget state back as hinted on the file.

Now, note that this file is indeed just a *hint*, and its contents *can be wrong* (as its Json, any user can edit it like CSS). In case the file doesn't exist, or the data stored on the file is wrong, as our loading function shouldn't fail at all, there're always default values at ready for every key.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QComboBox, QMenuBar, QButtonGroup, QRadioButton
import json

CONTEXT_FILENAME = 'settings.json'

class Scene(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ledit = QLineEdit()
        self.rdbA = QRadioButton('Option A')
        self.rdbB = QRadioButton('Option B')
        self.rdbC = QRadioButton('Option C')
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.group = QButtonGroup()

        self.group.addButton(self.rdbA, 100)
        self.group.addButton(self.rdbB, 200)
        self.group.addButton(self.rdbC, 300)

        self.combo.addItem('Item 1', 111)
        self.combo.addItem('Item 2', 222)
        self.combo.addItem('Item 3', 333)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.ledit)
        layout.addWidget(self.rdbA)
        layout.addWidget(self.rdbB)
        layout.addWidget(self.rdbC)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(layout)

    # Saves current widget states and values into a context object, and convert it
    # into a JSON String, which will be saved into a corresponding file that can be
    # loaded later on.
    #
    # In Short:
    #            WIDGETS -> CONTEXT OBJ -> JSON STRING -> FILE
    #
    def save(self):
        context = {}

        context['ledit-text'] = self.ledit.text()
        context['radio-selected'] = self.group.checkedId()
        context['combo-current'] = self.combo.currentData()

        try:
            fp = open(CONTEXT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        except Exception as error:
            print('Failed to create the save: ', error)
            return False
        else:
            data = b''
            try:
                data = json.dumps(context).encode('utf-8')
            except Exception as error:
                print('Failed to convert to JSON String: ', error)
                fp.close()
                return False
            else:
                fp.write(data)
                fp.close()
                return True

    # Loads context saved as a JSON String in an known file, and reset each widget
    # based on the loaded context. If no such file exists, use default values.
    #
    # In Short:
    #            FILE -> JSON STRING -> CONTEXT OBJ -> WIDGETS
    #
    def load(self):
        context = {}

        try:
            fp = open(CONTEXT_FILENAME, 'rb')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            context = {}
        except Exception as error:
            print('another exception just occurred: ', error)
            context = {}
        else:
            data = fp.read()
            fp.close()

            try:
                context = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
            except Exception as error:
                print('failed to load JSON String: ', error)
                context = {}

        self.ledit.setText(context.get('ledit-text', ''))

        radio = context.get('radio-selected', -1)
        button = self.group.button(radio)
        if (button is not None):
            button.setChecked(True)
        else:
            self.rdbA.setChecked(True)

        index = self.combo.findData(context.get('combo-current', -1))
        if (index == -1):
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
        else:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(index)

    # Catch the close event, and automatically save before the app closes.
    def closeEvent(self, ev):
        self.save()
        ev.accept()

###

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = Scene()
    win.load()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```